# NodeJS application layout and variable passing

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi guys I'm having a small problem with an application layout.  I'm setting my controllers up like this.

```
ApplicationController = function(_app) {
    this.app = _app;
    console.log(this.app); //this works
};

ApplicationController.prototype.index = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(this.app); //this is undefined
    res.json("hello");
};

module.exports = function(app) {
    return new ApplicationController(app);
};
```

And in my routes file I'm doing this.

```
module.exports = function(app) {

    //require controllers
    var Application = require('./controllers/ApplicationController')(app);       


    //define routes
    app.get('/', Application.index);
    app.get('/blah', Application.blah);

    return app;
};
```

The app variable I'm passing is not showing up in the other instance methods.  Is there a reason for this that I'm missing?  Thanks for any help.

In the past I've set my controllers up like this.

```
module.exports = function(app) {

    var controller = {

            //app is defined
            res.render('index', {
                title: "Index"
            });
        }
    };

    return controller;
};
```

But I like this other pattern more and I'm more curious then anything why it won't work.

Comment: How are you using `Application` after you `require()` it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing these lines:

```
app.get('/', Application.index);
app.get('/blah', Application.blah);
```

to:

```
app.get('/', Application.index.bind(Application));
app.get('/blah', Application.blah.bind(Application));
```

Your routes aren't being called in the context of your `Application` instance otherwise.

Comment: Ahh I see.  That makes sense.  I wasn't too familiar with binding or how I would use it(at least in the client side) but it makes more sense now.  Just wondering.. why does it work in the second situation?  I'm guessing I still couldn't split the methods outside the object.

Comment: Never mind I see.  The app variable is within scope of all those functions.  So if I wrapped the instance method definitions in modules.export function it would work(without the binding)